# SQL Search string column - approx 1M records, user enters search terms on form

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I have a SQL Server table containing about 1 million rows - and I want to allow users to search on an `Address` column of type `nvarchar(300)`.

Users can enter multiple words as their search term.

An address field may look like

```
15 Allendale, Donabate, Co. Dublin K36KP03
```

Users may search for any number of terms such as `15 Allendale` - `Allendale` - `K36KP03` - `Allendale Dublin`

Rather than using `LIKE %%` - is there a smarter approach? And any way I can determine which is a stronger match?

Comment: In the SQL Server there is Full Text Search. I guess, you can have a look on it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: You can try SQL Server Full Text search, but if already, I would recommend some you to look into solr or elasticsearch instead.

Comment: The "smarter" approach would be to normalise the data, your Address column contains multiple distinct values ie town, postcode etc - this information should be in dedicated columns which would make appropriate indexing and searching much easier.

Comment: Thanks - I've gone with the full text index - and it is shockingly quick.